# Abstraction in Object oriented programming

Tags: java, python, oop, computer-science, abstraction

"in Object-oriented programming, abstraction is a process of hiding the implementation details from the user, only the functionality will be provided to the user."

i have been trying to understand abstraction, can someone tell how exactly are we are hiding implementation details?using a program

Answer (score -1):

OOP Abstraction is used to facilitate tasks between multiples classes.  Let's say that we have a class A and a class B that both implement a method fruit() that works the same way for the two classes.
You could use an abstract class C that would define that method, class A and B will extend class C and you wouldn't have to repeat that method twice.
This is a small-case scenario, if you had hundreds of classes, it would be very worthwhile to save the data used to repeat that same methods.